# mainDiv.innerHTML = external file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `code.js` file which contains the following:

```
DivDialogHTML = function(){
  var mainDiv = document.createElement("div");
  mainDiv.id = "optin_settings_dialog";
  mainDiv.className = "OptinDialog";
  mainDiv.innerHTML = "<div>Text</div>";
}
```

The code to load the popup (dont know if it's all code, but to get the idea):

```
DivDialogOverlayHTML = function(){
  var mainDiv = document.createElement("div");
  mainDiv.id = "optin_settings_overlay_dialog";
  mainDiv.className = "OptinDialog";
  return mainDiv;
}


renderOptinWindow = function(){
  var pageHead = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
  var pageBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  if( pageHead && pageBody ){
    pageBody.appendChild( this.getDivDialogHTML() );
  }
}
```

Instead of using the `mainDiv.innerHTML = '<div>Text</div>'` I'd like the `mainDiv.innerHTML` to open another file (`Dialog.html`).
How do I do that?

Comment: If you wish to open another page inside your current page, you can use an iframe.

Answer (score 2):

with Ajax. But why not using jQuery?

```
$('.selector').load(url);
```

In your case you have to insert jQuery first like this in your

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And than take your existing function and change it like this

```
DivDialogHTML = function(){
    var $mainDiv = jQuery("div");
    $mainDiv.attr('id', "optin_settings_dialog");
    $mainDiv.addClass("OptinDialog");
    /* $mainDiv.html("<div>Text</div>"); */
    $mainDiv.load('Dialog.html');
}
```

Comment: Hmm not sure how to implement those solutions.. Code wasn't build by me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean another window? If so, please take a look at `window.open`

[window.open](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

After you create new window, you put its contents and display

Comment: The js code actually opens a popup (not in a new window but within the page). That's why the code is written within the innerHTML.
But I'd like to open an external file for that same purpose.

I want my clients to edit the Dialog.html file and not the code.js.

Comment: I also tried the iframe method, but that's also not what I want.

Comment: Please specify what would be your desired result

Comment: My desired end result would be 1 page with a (html js) popup.
The content of the popup should load via Dialog.html.

Comment: If you're using jQuery you could load content of `dialog.html` via `$("<element>).load('dialog.html');`  into another element and then display it. So Actually your whole code would be: `$('<div id="s2m_cookies.optin_settings_dialog" class="s2mCookiesOptinDialog"></div>').load("Dialog.html")`

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use **jQuery** you can use an **iframe**

**HTML**

```
<iframe id="optin_settings_dialog"></iframe>
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById("optin_settings_dialog").src="Dialog.html";
```